# Aggregate same connecting rows in pandas Dataframe (Time series groups)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Assume a time series f.e.:

```
Time  Hours col1  col2  col3
10:00     2 True  True  False
12:00     1 True  True  False
13:00     2 False False False
15:00     1 False False False
16:00     1 True  True  False
17:00     1 True  True  False
```

I want to group the rows with same boolean values, but only if they are connected.
The result should be as follows:

```
Time  Hours col1  col2  col3
10:00     3 True  True  False
13:00     3 False False False
16:00     2 True  True  False
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If need grouping by consecutive boolean first create consecutive groups by `shift`, `any` and `cumsum` and and then aggregate `first` for all columns without `Hours`, it aggregate by `sum`:

```
df1 = df.select_dtypes(bool)

g = df1.ne(df1.shift()).any(axis=1).cumsum()
d = dict.fromkeys(df.columns, 'first')
d['Hours'] = 'sum'

df = df.groupby(g).agg(d)
print (df)
    Time  Hours   col1   col2   col3
1  10:00      3   True   True  False
2  13:00      3  False  False  False
3  16:00      2   True   True  False
```

Comment: Nice thank you! The cumsum() was the function I couldn't figure out.

Answer (score 0):

you could do:

````
cond = (df[['col1', 'col2', 'col3']] == df[['col1', 'col2', 'col3']].shift()).all(axis=1)
df.groupby(cond[::-1].cumsum()).agg(dict(Time='first',  Hours='sum', 
                                        col1='first', col2="first", col3='first'))
```
````